# Network connection on an Acer Aspire 5253?

Tags: networking, acer

I bought an **Acer Laptop 5253-BZ893** and i got Ubuntu 10.10 installed with no problem.

The only problem i have is, that i get no network connection options, wired or wireless. I just get

> No Network Devices Available

The computer came with Windows 7 installed and I am able to connect to my wireless network fine using Windows.

I can not figure out why I can't get a network connection in Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `ifconfig` and post the output here

Comment: inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0

Comment: I would have expected a little more info.... open a terminal and try `sudo lshw -c network` and post **everything** that it displays

Comment: I just purchased an aspire 5253-bz602, and have the same problem when installing fedora 14. It stems from the wireless adapter being turned off, and having no on/off switch like most laptops. Instead, the wireless adapter gets turned on using the fn+f3 key combination, which doesn't appear to work without windows. I'm contacting Acer to see if there is a method for switching the adapter on manually. I'll post back with whatever I find out.

Comment: where you able to fix issue?

Answer (score -1):

well, you may be using the desktop edition. in ultimate edition you will be having both drivers installed on it. i used ubuntu 10.04 desktop and ultimate edition.but only wireless driver is missing in desktop. wired connection  is working fine. in ultimate edition both are working fine.you have two solutions i think

1. simply change the version of ubuntu or install ultimate edition.

2.else install the driver for wired connection after downloading it from windows.
and then wireless driver can be installed by giving the following command in a terminal
sudo apt-get install driver
(here driver should be replaced with the name of the driver for ubuntu 10.10)
it will ask for administrator password. give it. after that it will connect to internet automatically(with the wired connection) and will install the drivers for you.

Comment: Windows drivers will not work on the Ubuntu OS without installing `ndiswrapper`. I doubt fuquam would know about the 'ultimate edition' of Ubuntu either

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried Ubuntu Ultimate by windows install but my pointer did not work. Reinstalled 10.10. I still can't get an internet connection wired or wireless. Mac works fine. Windows 7 on this machine works fine. I downloaded the drivers for this machine but without an internet connection I can't install it when logged on to ubuntu.

Comment: When the computer is hooked directly into the router the light is not on. If it didn't work in Windows 7 on the same machine I'd swear there was a problem with the computer.

Comment: How do I install ndiwrapper without an internet connection. Doesn't that rely on Python?